# Timeout while connecting to remote debugger Expo

Tags: reactjs, debugging, react-native, expo

Hi i'm creating a new application with react native and expo and i would like to use debug provided by google. When i try to start it in my smarthphone's screen appears this error:
**Unable to connect with remote debugger
Timeout while connecting to remote debugger.**

Anyone can help me with this error?

Answer (score 0):

I was having this error with RN 0.51 and updating my Google Chrome to the latest version (63) fixed the error.